# Pushing a detail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have my tableView connected to a database table.
When I tap on a row I push a view with all the details of the item. Every thing works fine.

This is the code in the main class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *titleString = [(NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"item"] autorelease];
    NSString *category = [(NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"groupid"] autorelease];
    NSNumber *priceNumber = [(NSNumber *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"price"] autorelease];
    NSString *priceString = [[priceFormatter stringFromNumber: priceNumber] autorelease];
    NSDate *date = [(NSDate *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"dateadded"] autorelease];
    NSString *dateString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] autorelease];
    NSNumber *IO = [(NSNumber *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"incout"] autorelease];

    detailViewController.stringTitle = titleString;
    detailViewController.categoryVar = category;
    detailViewController.priceVar = priceString;
    detailViewController.dateVar = dateString;
    detailViewController.IOVar = IO;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

and this in the DetailsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = stringTitle;
    nome.text = stringTitle;
    prezzo.text = priceVar;
    data.text = dateVar;
    if ([IOVar isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        categoria.hidden = NO;
        categoriaLabel.hidden = NO;
        photoLabel.hidden = NO;
        categoria.text = categoryVar;
    } else if ([IOVar isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]){
        categoria.hidden = YES;
        categoriaLabel.hidden = YES;
        photoLabel.hidden = YES;
        categoria.text = @"";
    }
}
```

If I push and go back more than 3 times my app crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m

Thanks if you read till here, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Well guys, you all gave me the correct answer, but i MUST choose Snips as best for his "Call Of Duty" joke!
Thanks a lot to everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That definitely sounds like you're over-releasing an object (aka a 'zombie').

Xcode Instruments is an excellent tool for tracking down zombies.

Read about it here, and give it a go.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

It's much more fun than killing zombies in Call of Duty ;-)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are over-releasing your variables. You are pulling the ivars for your detail controller from a dictionary, which is from an array. After you assign them to a string, you autorelease them. I think that is the problem. You are emptying the data array. When you request it at a later row select, you try to access array or dictionary objects that do not exist any more --> EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to autorelease the values you get from the dictionary because you do not own them. [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1): You own the object either if you create it using  a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, or if you take ownership by retaining it.

In your case the code should be:

```
detailViewController.stringTitle = [rowVals objectForKey:@"item"];
```

etc.